# Lógica para variáveis Boolean no ASP

Tags: windows, asp, variáveis

Bom dia, faço manutenção em um sistema enorme, temos dois servidores, um de teste e outro de produção, acontece que estou com o seguinte problema:

No servidor de testes essa condição não retorna como verdadeira(True), mas no de produção retorna.

```
if Variavel Then Response.Write "OK" end if
```

Porém, se eu fizer assim

```
if Variavel = True then Response.Write "OK" end if
```

Aí retorna verdadeiro em ambos os servidores, se eu apenas mudar, colocar o True em todas, resolveria, mas existem muitas variaveis em muitos locais, e mudar tudo seria inviável, gostaria de saber se tem como configurar, dentro do proprio arquivo .asp algo que force o retorno como True mesmo se eu não especificar no if.

Comment: faz muuuito tempo que nao mexo com asp classico.. mas talvez seja um servidor esteja em PT e outro EN. Uma tentativa seria colocar no global.asa: Session.LCID = 1046 que define PT ou entao o que define EN

Comment: Olá, bom dia, isso mesmo, coloque como resposta por favor, para que possa aceita-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode estar acontecendo de um server estar em PT/BR e outro em EN. Uma forma seria adicionar no Global.asa a configuração, para que ambos fiquem no mesmo formato:

```
<script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
   Sub Session_OnStart()
      'formato padrão PT/BR
       Session.LCID = 1046
   End Sub

   Sub Session_OnEnd
   End Sub
</script>
```